# How to export a large data set to Excel from SAS?

Tags: excel, sas, export

I have generated a SAS data set which is very large and I can't export all the values from the data set into Excel.

Comment: Why can't you? Is the excel file too big to open? Do you have more than 1 million rows?

Comment: yes, there are like 6 million rows.

Comment: Yeah, I think Excel supports around a million rows not 6 million unfortunately. You can create an access DB maybe and link to it from Excel, but working with 6 million rows in Excel is going to be almost impossible. You could split it into multiple files or sheets.

Comment: how can i split it into multiple files or sheet ?  is there a way to do it automatically while i export data set from sas to excel.

Comment: If you have a variable you can split it by possibly using ODS Tagsets.excelxp and BY option. But the files are XML, and bigger than Excel files. This issue is well documented online.

Comment: why would you want to put 6 million rows of data into Excel? You should follow @Reeza 's advice and put in Access. From Access, you can query the data in Excel.

Comment: I found the solution for this. First, i used Proq sort to sort the dataset, then i used data statement to split this dataset ( with 6 million records ) into 5 different dataset. After doing this i have exported all 5 datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. First, i used PROC SORT to sort the data set, then i used DATA STATEMENT to split this data set ( with 6 million records ) into 5 different data set. After doing this i have exported all 5 data sets.